# What are the standard Linux directories?

Tags: linux

What are the standard Linux directories, like `/etc`?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/24523/meaning-of-directories-on-unix-and-unix-like-systems

Answer (score 19):

You're looking for the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem%5FHierarchy%5FStandard), and the [Linux Standards Base](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Standard_Base), which [builds on it](http://refspecs.linux-foundation.org/LSB%5F3.2.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/execenvfhs.html).

Answer (score 10):

/bin - common binaries

/sbin - Binaries used for system administration are placed here.

/boot - static files of the boot loader

/dev - device files such as your CD drive, hard disk, and any other physical device.

/home - user home directories are found here.

/lib - Essential shared libraries and kernel modules

/mnt - temporary mount point useful for when you insert your USB stick etc.

/var - variable data, such as logs, news, mail spool files and so on which is constantly being modified by various programs running on your system.

/tmp - temporary files are placed here by default.

/usr - the secondary hierarchy which contain its own bin and sbin sub-directories.

/etc - Usually contain the configuration files for all the programs that run on your system.

/opt - Third party application packages which does not conform to the standard Linux file 
hierarchy can be installed here.

/srv - Contains data for services provided by the system.

Comment: Umm... what was the point in asking a question you already had the answer to?

Comment: @skaffman - probably trying to get the self-learner badge or just whoring for rep :)

Comment: Should that question have had "...Rhetorical" at the end of it?

Comment: so is 1/4 a wiki, it's stuff i'd like to keep here

Comment: there's a self-learner badge...? gimme a break Eric

Comment: also, It's just a starter answer anyway, I'll refine it over time...

Answer (score 1):

Debian definition:
http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-opersys.html

This one seems "good enough" for me to link it, but I don't know what's the exact origin:
http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html

The google keyword is  "file system hierarchy".

Answer (score 0):

If you will look to the right -->  There is a Related section that has a link to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/24523/meaning-of-directories-on-unix-and-unix-like-systems) which provides the same information as the question you asked and answered.