# is this unix /var/blay/blah some kind of example convention?

Tags: unix

Whenever I see unix tutorials, I see them using:

/var/...

is var just a placeholder for an example?

Answer (score 4):

No. `/var` is a directory. It tends to contains "variable" data - that is data that is going to tend to change and often not configuration files. (eg. `/var/mail` for mail storage, `/var/vm` for where virtual memory is stored)

For more information on how directories are laid out on Unix check out question [24523](https://serverfault.com/questions/24523/meaning-of-directories-on-unix-and-unix-like-systems)

Comment: in your example directory is a more appropriate term http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folder_(computing)#The_folder_metaphor

Answer (score 2):

No, `/var` is a directory in the filesystem. One of the directories often referred to that exists under that is `/var/log` where most of the system and many of the application logs are kept.

"foo", "bar", "baz" and the like are placeholders.

Comment: "foo", "bar" and "baz" are traditional metasyntactic variables (http://www.jasonantman.com/jargon/entry.php?id=metasyntactic-variable)

Comment: Or **go to the source**. **esr** is the maintainer of the Jargon File and the author of The New Hacker's Dictionary. http://catb.org/jargon/html/M/metasyntactic-variable.html

Answer (score 1):

The top-level unix directory names are largely influenced by how these systems were configured decades ago. Here's a quick run-down of the more common ones:

- **/bin/** - programs that are part of the "core" of the system, i.e. required at startup
- **/boot/** - files requried during the boot process of the system (such as the kernel)
- **/dev/** - device nodes (placeholder files representing devices such as disks)
- **/etc/** - your configuration files
- **/home/** - directories belonging to actual users
- **/lib/** - shared librararies and other files that are part of the installed programs, but not directly runnable.
- **/sbin/** - same as `/bin`, but should only be run by root.
- **/tmp/** - temporary files (anyone can use this directory)
- **/usr/** - files that aren't system-critical, but are part of the system.
- **/var/** - files that change, but should be retained between boots

Traditionally, `/usr` was actually mounted as a network filesystem once the system was operational. So `/bin` and `/sbin` (which were stored on the local machine) only contained the stuff necessary to get that remote access up and running. `/usr/` in turn contains elements of the "standard" directory tree, including `/usr/bin/`, `/usr/sbin/`, `/usr/lib/`, `/usr/etc/`, etc.

In the same way, `/usr/local/` contained a set of programs, files, etc., that were "local" to a given installation, i.e. not part of the standard distribution. Again, expect to see `/usr/local/bin/`, `/usr/local/lib/`, etc. On a newly installed machine, those directories should be relatively empty, and it's a pretty safe place to install your own programs without creating any conflicts with the base system.

Traditionally, `/tmp/` was erased upon boot, so stuff put there shoudn't need to stick around. `/var/` on the other hand, contains a more permanant storage area. Things that end up under `/var/` include database files, log files, and mail boxes.

If all the packages on your system are well-behaved, you should be able to put the entire system on read-only media (such as a CD), except have `/var/` (and maybe `/home/`) be on a writable device, and `/tmp/` be a ramdrive.