# Linux - What do the common root folder names mean?

Tags: linux, directory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Meaning of directories on Unix and Unix like systems](https://serverfault.com/questions/24523/meaning-of-directories-on-unix-and-unix-like-systems)

I am rather new to linux, but I have installed a few different flavors. I noticed they all have similar folder names in the root directory

```
bin
boot
dev
etc
home
lib
lost+found
media
mnt
opt
proc
root
sbin
selinux
srv
sys
tmp
usr
var
```

I googled around, but couldn't find anywhere that explained the purpose of each of these. I understand a couple, but could anyone point me somewhere or give a quick breakdown of the common ones.

Comment: `man hier` and http://www.pathname.com/fhs/ , until I find the duplicate to close on :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is well defined by the File System Hierarchy Standard (FHS).

[Wikipedia Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard)
[FHS Website](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/)

Answer (score 2):

Most of these directories are described in the: [Linux Filesystem Hierarchy](http://tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/index.html)