# What are the best practices of the usr, var, and etc folders?

Tags: unix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Meaning of directories on Unix and Unix like systems](https://serverfault.com/questions/24523/meaning-of-directories-on-unix-and-unix-like-systems)

I'm confused about the different uses for 3 of the standard "root-level" folders: `/var /etc /usr`

What are the different use cases for these directories?

Answer (score 17):

"/etc" is used for configurations (.conf files etc). here you find all the configs and settings for your system.

"/usr" is used for "user programs". Usually your package manager installs all the binaries, shared files etc. from all programs here (except config files, which go to /etc). You can check /usr/bin for binaries, /usr/share for shared files (media, etc), /usr/share/doc for documentation,...

There is also an "/opt" folder, where there are "other" programs usually put (mostly binary programs, or programs installed from other sources (not the default package manager). Some programs like that (usually compiled) also go to "/usr/local"

"/var" is usually used for log files, 'temporary' files (like mail spool, printer spool, etc), databases, and all other data not tied to a specific user. Logs are usually in "/var/log", databases in "/var/lib" (mysql - "/var/lib/mysql"), etc.

Comment: What does lib in varlib mean? Why lib?

Comment: @Pacerier lib is short for library/libraries.

Comment: @devios1 still doesn't really explain why that folder is so called. mysql is not a library.

Comment: @samlaf: `/var`, as the name implies, is for _variable_ (read/write) data that's _persistent_ across reboots (unlike temporary data in `/tmp`), in contrast with the (mostly) read-only `/usr`. As for `/var/lib`, in this particular case the `lib` subdir means "library" only in a very broad sense, as it actually stands for any specific software or package, as opposed to more general, system-wide subdirs like `/var/log` which don't belong to any particular package. MySQL example, its read-only files go to `/usr/*/mysql`, settings at `/etc/mysql`, and read/write databases at `/var/lib/mysql`

Answer (score 3):

The `/etc/` directory is a common location to put configuration files. (But not the ONLY one by any means.)

The `/var` directory is the location for "variable" things like logs, running process ID pointer files, spool directories, and other things important for running services.

The `/usr/` directory is where user-accessible applications are generally located. Also a case of "by no means all".

Comment: So what would the definition of /usr/etc be?

Comment: config files for user-supplied application, probably. Personally, I prefer to keep THOSE things over in /opt if they're not part of a package provided with the OS or Distribution.

Comment: Mind you, none of this is a "rule". It's more tradition and convention and it's transgressed often enough in practice, but is generally-considered a good idea to follow.

Comment: Right, that's more what I'm aiming towards is best practices. Perhaps a title change?